# Laravel string limit with html tag shows less item than the actual number of items

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel and blade to loop over some blog items. I wanted to show blog with html tags and also with str_limit function.

When I try

```
{!!str_limit($blog->body, 450)!!}
```

It only shows 10 blogs or 11 out of 22. It should show all items.

If I use `{{ str_limit($blog->body, 450) }}` it shows all but without html tags I mean no effect of html tag.

Comment: I suspect what's happening is you've got some un-closed HTML tags because `str_limit` is lopping them off. For example, if the HTML code `<a href="http://google.com/">This is a link</a>` got cut off at `<a href="http://`, the next blog entry's text will be still inside the `<a href="">` tag you've got open. Take a look at the source code and pay particular attention to syntax highlighting where the missing items are.

Comment: In this case, what to do because finding which tag which is kept open is seems impossible.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it and you are correct. It seems iframe src was not closed. you can post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_limit` has no knowledge of HTML tags, so using it on a string that contains HTML will often result in an unclosed tag that breaks the rest of the page.

As an example, an excerpt that ends in `<a href="http://google.co` because it got lopped off there means the rest of your page is part of the `<a>` tag until you accidentally output a `"` and a `>` again.

A couple options are available to you:

- Strip the HTML tags. I know you wanted to preserve them, but this remains the easiest way of generating an excerpt.
- Output the entire body, but give it max height and an `overflow: hidden` to hide the rest. This has bandwidth downsides, so if your posts are enormously long, it may not be the best approach.
- Produce your own excerpts as a separate field. Manual work, but you're always in control that way.
- Find/code a HTML-aware excerpt generator. I'm not aware of a good one I can recommend - it's a complicated problem. You could try generating a `str_limit`ed string and then running the results through [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php), which can *sort of* fix invalid HTML.